# Subsetting and Looping a Time Series Data in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset of timeseries (30 years). I did a subset for the month and the date I want (shown below in the code). Is there a way to do a loop for each month and the days in those month? Also, is there a way to save the plots automatically, in different folders corresponding to each month? Right now I am doing it manually by changing the month and date which corresponds to `dfOct31all <- df [ which(df$Month==10 & df$Day==31), ]`in the code below then plotting and saving it. By the way, I'm using RStudio.
Can someone please guide me?
Thanks!

```
setwd("WDir")
df <- read.csv("Velocity.csv", header = TRUE)
attach(df)

#Day 31

dfOct31all <- df [ which(df$Month==10 & df$Day==31), ]
dfall31Mbs <- dfOct31all[c(-1,-2,-3)]
densities <- lapply(dfall31Mbs, density)

par(mfcol=c(5,5), oma=c(1,1,0,0), mar=c(1,1,1,0), tcl=-0.1, mgp=c(0,0,0))

plot(densities[[1]], col="black",main = "1000mb",xlab=NA,ylab=NA)
plot(densities[[2]], col="black",main="925mb",xlab=NA,ylab=NA)
plot(densities[[3]], col="black",main="850mb",xlab=NA,ylab=NA)
plot(densities[[4]], col="black",main="700mb",xlab=NA,ylab=NA)
plot(densities[[5]], col="black",main="600mb",xlab=NA,ylab=NA)
plot(densities[[6]], col="black",main="500mb",xlab=NA,ylab=NA)
plot(densities[[7]], col ="black",main="400mb",xlab=NA,ylab=NA)
plot(densities[[8]], col="black",main="300mb",xlab=NA,ylab=NA)
plot(densities[[9]], col="black",main="250mb",xlab=NA,ylab=NA)
plot(densities[[10]], col="black",main="200mb",xlab=NA,ylab=NA)
plot(densities[[11]], col= "black",main="150mb",xlab=NA,ylab=NA)
plot(densities[[12]], col= "black",main="100mb",xlab=NA,ylab=NA)
plot(densities[[13]], col = "black",main="70mb",xlab=NA,ylab=NA)
plot(densities[[14]], col="black",main="50mb",xlab=NA,ylab=NA)
plot(densities[[15]], col="black",main="30mb",xlab=NA,ylab=NA)
plot(densities[[16]], col = "black",main="20mb",xlab=NA,ylab=NA)
plot(densities[[17]], col="black",main="10mb",xlab=NA,ylab=NA)
```

Snippet of data is shown as well

```
Year Month Day 1000mb  925mb  850mb   700mb  600mb  500mb   400mb   300mb   250mb   200mb   150mb   100mb   70mb    50mb    30mb    20mb    10mb
1984    10  31 6       6.6    7.9     11.5   14.6   17      20.8    25.8    26.4    25.3    24.4    22.7    19.9    19.2    20.4    24.8    30.8
1985    10  31 5.8     7.1    7.7     11.5   14.7   17.3    25.3    32.6    32.9    32.4    27.1    20.9    14.2    9.7     6.4     7.3     7.4
1986    10  31 4.3     6.1    7.7     11.3   18.4   26.3    34.4    44.5    48.9    46.2    34.5    20.4    13.8    13.2    21.7    31      46.4
1987    10  31 2.2     2.9    4       7      9      13.9    19.9    25.8    26.6    23.7    17.3    12      7       3.1     1.7     5.8     14.1
1988    10  31 2.5     2.1    2.3     6.5    6.4    5.1     7.4     12.1    13.4    16.1    16.7    15.2    8.8     5       2.8     6.2     8.9
1989    10  31 3.4     4      4.7     4.4    4.1    4       4.6     4.8     5.9     5.6     10.9    13.9    12.3    10.4    8.1     8       8
1990    10  31 4       4.9    7.5     14.6   19     21.9    25.7    28.3    29.4    29.2    27.3    18      12.6    10.1    9       12      19.9
1991    10  31 2.8     3.2    4       10.8   12.1   11.2    9.9     9.1     9.9     12.8    18      17.5    10.4    6.3     4.2     7.6     11.7
1992    10  31 5.9     6.9    7.9     13.1   17.9   25.2    34.6    47.3    53.3    53      42.4    21.3    11.6    6       4.6     8.5     12.8
1993    10  31 2.3     1.5    0.4     3.6    6.3    10.1    14.3    19.1    21.6    21.8    18.4    13.6    12.3    9.5     6.9     11      18.1
1994    10  31 2       2.2    3.8     11.6   17     19.8    23.6    24.9    25.5    26.2    28.4    25.2    16.7    13.6    9.3     8.3     9.8
1995    10  31 1.5     2      3.4     7.6    9.1    11.2    13.7    17.9    20.3    21.7    21.1    16.7    13      12.1    14.9    21.4    27.3
1996    10  31 1.9     2.4    3.5     8      11.7   17.4    26.4    35.6    33.3    24.6    12.4    4.1     0.5     3.4     7.2     9.4     11.6
1997    10  31 3.7     4.8    7.8     19.2   24.6   29.6    35.6    41      41.8    42      37.9    23.7    11.2    8.6     4.2     3.8     7
1998    10  31 0.7     1.1    0.9     4.8    8.4    11.4    14      25.3    29.7    25.2    15.9    6.6     2.1     1       4.5     8.9     6.1
1999    10  31 1.9     1.6    2.4     10.7   15.3   19      23.2    29      32.4    31.9    28      20.3    10.8    9.4     12      14.5    16.9
2000    10  31 5.1     5.8    6.7     12.8   18.2   23.9    29.9    40.7    42.2    33.7    23.5    12.7    2.6     1.6     3.8     4.7     5.1
2001    10  31 5.7     6.1    7.1     10.1   10.8   14.7    18.3    22.8    22.3    22.2    22      14      9.5     6.6     5.2     6.5     8.6
2002    10  31 1.4     1.6    1.8     9.2    14.5   19.5    24.8    30      30.5    27.6    22.2    13.9    9.1     7.1     8.5     16.1    23.8
2003    10  31 1.5     1.3    0.7     1      3.5    6       11.7    21.5    21.9    22.9    23      20.7    15.8    12.5    14.5    20.1    26
2004    10  31 5.4     5.6    6.9     14.4   23.3   33.3    46.1    60.9    62.1    54.6    42.9    28      17.3    12.3    10.1    13.6    13.3
2005    10  31 1.7     1.3    3       10.3   15.8   19.5    21.1    22.8    24.1    24.5    24.5    20.6    13.5    10.7    10      10.7    10.4
2006    10  31 2.3     1.5    1.7     8.7    12.5   15.9    18.7    20.5    21.8    24.3    29.9    25.3    18.3    12.8    7.7     8.8     12.4
2007    10  31 3.7     2.7    2.3     2.2    2.6    4.2     6.5     11.9    15.9    19.6    17.2    9.5     6.9     5.7     4.9     5.8     11.7
2008    10  31 7.7     10.8   14.3    20.3   23     25.8    27.4    32.1    35.4    34.8    25.8    13.2    7.1     2.9     2.6     3.4     6
2009    10  31 0.5     0.2    2       9.3    13.5   17.6    18.8    20.8    21.4    21.2    18.9    14.2    11.1    6.4     1.9     3       8
2010    10  31 5.6     6.8    8.5     13.4   16.5   20.3    23.8    26.8    31      28.1    24      15.7    9.9     7       4.8     3.9     1.8
2011    10  31 5.9     6.7    5.6     7.9    10.3   11.8    12.5    16.2    19.5    21.4    17.9    13.2    9.6     7.9     8       8.3     10.8
2012    10  31 4.8     6.3    9.4     19.5   24.2   27.2    27.5    27.3    27.7    30.7    27.5    16.7    10      7.6     8       13.8    19.7
2013    10  31 1.4     1.9    3.9     9.1    13.1   17.3    22.9    29.7    30.4    27.3    23.5    18.2    13.1    6.3     4.4     2.4     9.4
```

Comment: A few points. I'ts helpful to have an example of your data. You don't need to attach() your data - especially since you've gone to the trouble of using df$Month. Do you wan't a 5x5 matrix of plots for all conditions your looking to loop through. And since densities is a list you should apply another list wrapper to that to do your plotting.

Comment: Yes I would prefer that so that the 17 densities can fit on one plot page. I'm a R novice so I just went with what I knew in terms of the attach(df). How would I apply another list wrapper?

Comment: can you post an example of your data? And are the 17 densities you listed above the only plots you want?

Comment: @miles2know those are the only densities I want. I edited the post to include the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote it out for each day rather than doing a loop.